# Merging Google Spreadsheets Landscape

Tags: google-apps-script, merge, google-sheets, landscape

I am trying to merge multiple spreadsheets using a Google Apps Script.

My spreadsheets are formatted to print correctly as landscape.

I am able to merge them using the following section of code:

```
var coverss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(keyCover); //Open the cover     spreadsheet
var bodyss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(keyBody); // Open the body spreadsheet
var specialss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(keySpecial); //Open the Special's spreadsheet

var newSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("New Spreadsheet"); 

for (var y in coverss.getSheets()) {
  coverss.getSheets()[y].copyTo(newSpreadSheet);  //copy cover to new   spreadsheet
}

for (var y in bodyss.getSheets()) {    
  bodyss.getSheets()[y].copyTo(newSpreadSheet);  //copy all body sheets   to new spreadsheet
}

for (var y in specialss.getSheets()) {
  specialss.getSheets()[y].copyTo(newSpreadSheet); //copy specials   sheet to new spreadsheet
}

var delsheet = newSpreadSheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); //delete Sheet1   that was created when the new spreadsheet was created
newSpreadSheet.deleteSheet(delsheet);
```

My problem is that data in "New Spreadsheet" is now formatted as portrait.
When I print "New Spreadsheet" as landscape, it runs to a 2nd page is not centered. It is now the width of portrait.

Any ideas?